# Building specific modules in multimodular maven project + dependencies conditionally

Tags: maven, build, maven-3

When running `mvn install -pl "project1, project2, etc." -am -Pmy-profile`, maven will build the specified modules and *all* their dependencies which can take a while if there are a lot of dependencies.

That being said, some dependencies being compiled (due to the `-am` flag) may already exist in the local `.m2` repository and/or in `my-profile`, rendering their recompilation useless and often time consuming.

Is there any way to specify that maven should only build a given `-am` dependency if it does not already exist in `my-profile` nor locally in `.m2`?

---

Regarding the potential duplicate [Maven 2: Only build artifact if not already installed in local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333635/13927534):

In my case I do want to build the projects referenced after the `-pl` flag regardless of whether they were already built or not. It's the dependencies that are my problem. Also, that question is regarding Maven 2, perhaps things have changed since.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven 2: Only build artifact if not already installed in local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333635/maven-2-only-build-artifact-if-not-already-installed-in-local-repository)

Comment: This post is under discussion at [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426379/question-closed-for-lack-of-clarity).

Comment: Make a post the best self-contained presentation you can. Don't make readers go elsewhere, like another Q&A or version, put everything needed to ask in your post. Clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. If another Q&A is not a duplicate edit your post to make that clear in a self-contained way & again do not require us to go elsewhere. Quote & paraphrase with credit. The suggestion on meta to reference an earlier version is a bad idea. PS Avoid social & meta commentary in posts. PS Yes-or-no questions are seldom useful or asking for what's actually wanted. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Maven as shipped cannot do this. Once you use `-am` to specify that dependencies should be included in the reactor (or include/exclude them through profiles) there's nothing special about the original `-pl` list, so this is essentially a duplicate of [Maven 2: Only build artifact if not already installed in local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333635/maven-2-only-build-artifact-if-not-already-installed-in-local-repository), which has a similar answer to this one:

> The short answer is: there's no sane way to do that, Maven doesn't work that way.

You may get better results from use of [incremental builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918165/does-maven-support-incremental-builds), or from building your own scripting around Maven. You may also be able to make use of profiles to focus on a subset of the project, but there's no existing command-line flag or configuration option to get what you're asking for.